# How to remove busybox from linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, bootloader, u-boot

I've a Leopard board (with DM368 Ti processor) up and running.(Uboot + Linux Kernel + root fs)

Now, the problem is, i no longer need busybox (which is currently there)..So i removed it.( from /bin/busybox) and rebooted the board, but booting gives an error message saying - 
`Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found`

Is there anything else i've to remove to get it work ? Or am i doing anything wrong ?

Any help!
Thanks.

Comment: How did you figure that you no longer need `busybox`?

Comment: I just want to run my App at startup, and thats it. So i thought, its better not to have any other (redundant) apps on the board.

Comment: Apparently, `busybox` is not redundant at all.

Comment: Thats correct..but i dont need it!

Comment: _You_ might not need it, but your system needs it.

Comment: Oh.. Is it(removal of BBox) going to cause any instability to the system ??

Comment: Yes, it might render your system unable to boot.

Comment: Leave busybox alone, unless you really know what you are doing and are going to run your app as init and no startup scripts, mount commands, telnet, ANYTHING else. I build DMxxx embedded systems and use busybox for many things in finished products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BusyBox acts as the "init" process on the system; if you remove it then you need to find a new `init` to replace it with.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Could you please explain the statement "you need to find a new init to replace it with." a bit more as em a complete newbieee here :)

Comment: Just what I said. The kernel will try to execute `/sbin/init`. Make sure you have something executable there.

Comment: Something to execute? What exactly ? b/c /sbin/init was pointing to /init/bysybox (thats why busybox was running as init ...I guess), but i removed it , so what can i have there(in /sbin/init) now ?

Comment: @mujahid: please read more on the [`init` process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) and its history. Linux will try to execute `init` in the following order: `/sbin/init`, `/etc/init`, `/bin/init` and `/bin/sh`. However, if you have an initramfs (common on embedded systems), it will execute `/init` within it, which is usually a shell script which mounts important things and eventually does a `switch_root` (see [this](http://jootamam.net/howto-initramfs-image.htm)).